# psql hangs on a simple select or immediately after that

Tags: postgresql, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket pipeline to run psql migration. Migration script is hangs on a simple select or immediately after that. Here is my bitbucket pipeline step

```
 - step:
          name: Run miggartion
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.7.0
              variables:
                DEBUG: "true"
                SSH_USER: $USERNAME
                SERVER: $HOST
                COMMAND: 'sudo su - postgres -c "psql -d test -f /tmp/test.sql && echo test"'
                SSH_KEY: $KEY
```

I have this output

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
=
 set_config 
------------
 
(1 row)
```

Here is my migration script:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 15.3 (Debian 15.3-0+deb12u1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 15.3 (Debian 15.3-0+deb12u1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The question is why migration command hangs. Problem with ssh-run plugin